# Creates a for loop in Bigquery stored procedure

Tags: sql, loops, for-loop, stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I have created a stored procedure which takes 1 input each time using the below Bigquery

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `Summary_Typhoon_BlackRain`(TyphoonStart TIMESTAMP, TyphoonEnd TIMESTAMP, BlackRainStart TIMESTAMP, BlackRainEnd TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `Summary_Typhoon_BlackRain` AS(

SELECT -- Enter the time in UTC format not in HKT format
      PairingDutyId, 
      EmployeeCode,
      PairingDutyStartDate, PairingDutyEndDate, -- PairingDutyStartDate = Reporting Time, PairingDutyEndDate = Release Time
      ArrivalActual_UTC, -- Actual In Time (OOOI)
      Flight_No,
      DEPSTN, ARRSTN,
      (CASE 
          WHEN DEPSTN = 'HKG' AND TyphoonStart IS NOT NULL THEN
            CASE
              WHEN PairingDutyStartDate <= TIMESTAMP_ADD(TyphoonStart, INTERVAL -90 MINUTE) THEN 0
              WHEN PairingDutyStartDate >  TIMESTAMP_ADD(TyphoonStart, INTERVAL -90 MINUTE) AND PairingDutyStartDate < TIMESTAMP_ADD(TyphoonEnd, INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) THEN 1 
              WHEN PairingDutyStartDate >= TIMESTAMP_ADD(TyphoonEnd, INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) THEN 0
              ELSE 0
            END
          WHEN ARRSTN = 'HKG' AND TyphoonStart IS NOT NULL THEN
            CASE
              WHEN ArrivalActual_UTC <= TyphoonStart AND PairingDutyEndDate <= TyphoonStart THEN 0
              WHEN ArrivalActual_UTC <= TyphoonStart AND (PairingDutyEndDate > TyphoonStart AND PairingDutyEndDate < TyphoonEnd) THEN 1
              WHEN (ArrivalActual_UTC > TyphoonStart AND ArrivalActual_UTC < TyphoonEnd) AND (PairingDutyEndDate > TyphoonStart AND PairingDutyEndDate < TyphoonEnd) THEN 1
              WHEN (ArrivalActual_UTC > TyphoonStart AND ArrivalActual_UTC < TyphoonEnd) AND PairingDutyEndDate >= TyphoonEnd THEN 1
              WHEN ArrivalActual_UTC >= TyphoonEnd AND PairingDutyEndDate >= TyphoonEnd THEN 0
              ELSE 0
            END
        END) AS Typhoon,
      (CASE
        WHEN DEPSTN = 'HKG' AND BlackRainStart IS NOT NULL THEN
            CASE
              WHEN PairingDutyStartDate <= TIMESTAMP_ADD(BlackRainStart, INTERVAL -90 MINUTE) THEN 0
              WHEN PairingDutyStartDate >  TIMESTAMP_ADD(BlackRainStart, INTERVAL -90 MINUTE) AND PairingDutyStartDate < TIMESTAMP_ADD(BlackRainEnd, INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) THEN 1 
              WHEN PairingDutyStartDate >= TIMESTAMP_ADD(BlackRainEnd, INTERVAL 90 MINUTE) THEN 0
              ELSE 0
            END
      END) AS BlackRain
    FROM 
      `BlockHourAdjustment`);

END;
```

Right now,users can only input a pair of Typhoon time or Black Rainstorm time each time. However, I would like to set the input as a list for example ['2023-01-01 14:30:00.000 UTC','2023-01-20 15:30:00.000 UTC'] so that I dont need to inout the time one by one and concat the generated table manually.

So I would like to call the stored procedure for example:

```
DECLARE TyphoonStarts ARRAY<TIMESTAMP> DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE TyphoonEnds ARRAY<TIMESTAMP> DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE BlackRainStarts ARRAY<TIMESTAMP> DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE BlackRainEnds ARRAY<TIMESTAMP> DEFAULT NULL;
CALL `Summary_Typhoon_BlackRain`([TIMESTAMP '2023-07-16 16:40:00.000 UTC',TIMESTAMP '2023-08-31 18:40:00.000 UTC'], [TIMESTAMP '2023-07-17 08:40:00.000 UTC',TIMESTAMP '2023-09-01 08:20:00.000 UTC'], NULL, NULL);
```

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm whether the answer given below is helpful for you or not ?

Answer (score 0):

It was difficult to understand the question, but I believe I understood the requirement. You don't need a Stored Procedure for this purpose. You can leverage SQL CROSS JOIN to achieve this result. Please borrow the ideas from the below code block.

The following query is a table-generating function and outputs 5 rows. This we are considering as your complex query provided in the above question

```
SELECT row_id FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,5)) AS row_id;
```

| row_id |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

Now if you want to get 5 `base_data` * 2 `array_count` rows for 2 pairs of `typhoon.starts` and `typhoon.ends` defined in an array, run the below block.

```
DECLARE v_typhoon ARRAY<STRUCT<starts TIMESTAMP, ends timestamp>>;

SET v_typhoon = [
  STRUCT(TIMESTAMP '2023-07-16 16:40:00.000 UTC' AS starts, TIMESTAMP '2023-08-31 18:40:00.000 UTC' AS ends),
  STRUCT(TIMESTAMP '2023-07-17 08:40:00.000 UTC',TIMESTAMP '2023-09-01 08:20:00.000 UTC')
  ];

WITH base_data AS
(
SELECT row_id FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0,5)) AS row_id
)
SELECT
   row_id,
   TIMESTAMP_ADD(t.starts, INTERVAL -90*b.row_id MINUTE) AS starts_minus_90,
   TIMESTAMP_ADD(t.ends,   INTERVAL 90*b.row_id MINUTE)  AS ends_plus_90
FROM base_data b
    JOIN UNNEST(v_typhoon) AS t
ORDER BY row_id;
```